# SVR prediction syntax explanation

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction

I am working on a school project where we are using SVR to predict the next value of a series of values (e.g. stock values). We found some example code on scikit (Python) which we aren't able to understand the syntax for.

Could someone help us decipher this?

```
    X = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis=0)
    Y = np.sin(X).ravel()

    from sklearn.svm import SVR
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)

    y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(X, Y).predict(X)
```

I understand the first 4 lines of this code... my issue is more with the y_rbf line... how exactly does this work? Are we doing a curve fit based on the training set and then predicting based on the same input vector?

I am not sure what the syntax means. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The last line can be broken up into:

```
svr_rbf.fit(X, Y)   # 1
y_rbf = svr_rbf.predict(X)  # 2
```

1. You build a model of how the output y depends on X. According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.fit) you:

   > Fit the SVM model according to the given training data.
2. Here you use the model you built previously to predict the values (y) for each point. As the [documention](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.predict) puts it:

   > Perform regression on samples in X.

This is fine for an experiment, but just to make you aware: in general you'll want to test your model on data other than what was used to fit the model to avoid overfitting. You can read about cross-validation if you are not familiar with it.